# Fitting a multinomial glm for a very large dataset

Tags: r, regression, glm, multinomial, nnet

I have multinomial compositional data for 100 categories from two groups, where each is represented by two ages:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("g1",200),rep("g2",200)),
                 age = c(rep("a1",100),rep("a2",100),rep("a1",100),rep("a2",100)),
                 category = rep(paste0("c",1:100),4),
                 n = c(rmultinom(1,7000,pgamma(shape=0.8,rate=0.1,q=seq(0.01,1,0.01))),
                       rmultinom(1,5000,pgamma(shape=0.8,rate=0.3,q=seq(0.01,1,0.01))),
                       rmultinom(1,1800,pgamma(shape=0.5,rate=0.1,q=seq(0.01,1,0.01))),
                       rmultinom(1,1200,pgamma(shape=0.9,rate=0.1,q=seq(0.01,1,0.01)))),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to fit a regression model to estimate the interaction effect of the `category * group`, while controlling for `age`.

So far, I'm trying to use a `multicategorical` `glm` (with a `binomial(link = 'logit')`), to a `data.frame` where I transform the `df$n` (total counts) to a `binomial` (`binary`) form:

```
binomial.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df$group),function(g){
  do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(dplyr::filter(df,group == g)$age),function(a){
    do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(dplyr::filter(df,group == g)$category),function(t){
      sum.non.category <- sum(dplyr::filter(df,group == g & age == a & category != t)$n)
      sum.category <- sum(dplyr::filter(df,group == g & age == a & category == t)$n)
      data.frame(group = g,age = a,category = t,assigned.category = c(rep(0,sum.non.category),rep(1,sum.category)))
    })) 
  }))
}))

binomial.df$group <- factor(binomial.df$group, levels = c("g1","g2"))
binomial.df$age <- factor(binomial.df$age, levels = c("a1","a2"))
binomial.df$category <- factor(binomial.df$category, levels = paste0("c",1:100))

mm.fit <- glm(assigned.category ~ category * group + age,data = binomial.df, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
```

Clearly for this size of data the `glm` call will run for days or even longer, so I'm looking for a more tractable way.

Any idea?

BTW, I tried using `nnet`'s `multinom` first:

```
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = c("g1","g2"))
df$age <- factor(df$age, levels = c("a1","a2"))
df$category <- factor(df$category, levels = paste0("c",1:100))
mm.fit <- nnet::multinom(n ~ category * group + age, data=df)
```

But I get:

```
Error in nnet.default(X, Y, w, mask = mask, size = 0, skip = TRUE, softmax = TRUE,  : 
  too many (22220) weights
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about what the data is, and what you're hoping to do - are you testing hypotheses, or wanting to build a predictive model?  Also, why are you modelling your response (n) as multinomial, when it looks like a continuous count? What exactly is n? Do you really want to test for interactions between every level of category and group - all 200?

Comment: Can you not just model the counts directly? `model <- glm(n ~ category * group + age, data=df, family=poisson)`

Comment: I edited my post to specify that my data are compositional, so I think this may mean that I need a multinomial GLM (i.e. with the `binomial` `logit` `link` `function`). But I think that for the scale of data issue I'm having `biglm`'s `bigglm` is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `nnet::multinom` issue you can resolve by modifying your `multinom` call to include the argument `MaxNWts=100000` :

```
mm.fit <- nnet::multinom(n ~ category * group + age, data=df, MaxNWts=100000)
```

To fit large multinomial models in R you could also look into the `h20` package :

https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html